# JavaScript. Как сбросить все данные cookies сайта в браузере?

Tags: javascript, php

У меня на ресурсе реализована интеграция с ВК. Но в его куки с флагом httpOnly, Path другой. Как их очистить? Сделал на странице кнопку сброса сайта. Как правильно реализовать её функционал?

В идеале надо, чтобы после выполнения кода были стерты абсолютно все cookies, как будто это первое посещение сайта.

Comment: Что ваш сайт записывал и редактировал, то и надо очищать. Вам виднее, что.

Comment: @andreymal, У меня на сайте есть интеграция с Вконтактом. Но его куки с флагом httpOnly, Path другой. Как их очистить?

Comment: @Сергей Вам удалось решить свою задачу в итоге? Видел что ночью приняли ответ, а с утра убрали. Что-то не сработало?

Comment: @andreymal, я выяснил, что вконтакте ставит свои куки не только на моем сайте но и на домен vk.com. Получилась странная ситуация: Если нажимать кнопку в вкладке Application -> Clear Storage -> Clear Browser Dat в консоли браузера, то куки все стираются, но при обновлении страницы вконтакт помнит, что я заходил. Но если стереть Куки в вкладке Network -> выбрать домен моего сайта ->  левый клик мыши -> Clear browser cookies, то вк уже просит авторизоваться. Либо я чего-то не понимаю, либо в браузере Chrome ошибки. Потому что чем отличаются эти две кнопки? Сайт dz4all.ru.

Comment: А самое интересное(оно не всегда проявляется) то, что если после авторизации на сайте в режиме инкогнито в браузере, зайти на vk.com., то сайт меня опознает и не потребует пароль. И наоборот: Если зарегаться в вк, то на моем сайте уже будет авторизовано.

Answer (score 1):

Есть подозрение что в конкретно вашем случае с куками Вконтакте ничего не получится т.к. вы скорее всего упретесь в защиту через Same-origin policy.

Подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Тем не менее попробуйте такое решение.

### Решение

На javascript вы удалить httpOnly куки не сможете, т.к. у javascripta нет доступа к ним.

> Куки HTTPonly не доступны из JavaScript через свойства Document.cookie
>   API, что помогает избежать межсайтового скриптинга (XSS).
>   Устанавливайте этот флаг для тех cookie, к которым не требуется
>   обращаться через JavaScript. В частности, если куки используются
>   только для поддержки сеанса, то в JavaScript они не нужны, так что в
>   этом случае следует устанавливать флаг HttpOnly.

Подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8

Тем не менее вот код, который удалит всё остальное:

```
(function () {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");
    for (var c = 0; c < cookies.length; c++) {
        var d = window.location.hostname.split(".");
        while (d.length > 0) {
            var cookieBase = encodeURIComponent(cookies[c].split(";")[0].split("=")[0]) + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; domain=' + d.join('.') + ' ;path=';
            var p = location.pathname.split('/');
            document.cookie = cookieBase + '/';
            while (p.length > 0) {
                document.cookie = cookieBase + p.join('/');
                p.pop();
            };
            d.shift();
        }
    }
})();
```

### Чтобы удалить все куки

Чтобы удалить вообще все доступные к чтению куки в рамках вашего домена нужен вот такой скрипт на php:

```
// unset cookies 
if ( $_GET["clear_cookie"] == "true" ) {
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] ) ) {
        $cookies = explode( ';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] );
        foreach ( $cookies as $cookie ) {
            $parts = explode( '=', $cookie );
            $name  = trim( $parts[0] );
            setcookie( $name, '', time() - 1000 );
            setcookie( $name, '', time() - 1000, '/' );
        }
    }
}
```

Он должен стоять в самом начале вашего файла до всех header данных и вывода тегов .

А кнопку "очистить куки" просто сделайте ссылкой вида:

```
<a href="?clear_cookie=true">очистить куки</a>
```

### Демонстрация:

https://adudnik.ru/code-examples/clear_coockies.php - задается и выводится кука "name";
https://adudnik.ru/code-examples/clear_coockies.php?clear_cookie=true - все куки чистятся, смотрим что в куке "name" (ничего);

**Код демонстрации:**

```
<?php
// unset cookies
if (  $_GET["clear_cookie"] != "true" ) {
    $_COOKIE["name"] = "демонстрация";
}
//
if ( $_GET["clear_cookie"] == "true" ) {
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] ) ) {
        $cookies = explode( ';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] );
        foreach ( $cookies as $cookie ) {
            $parts = explode( '=', $cookie );
            $name  = trim( $parts[0] );
            setcookie( $name, '', time() - 1000 );
            setcookie( $name, '', time() - 1000, '/' );
        }
    }
}
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
var_dump($_COOKIE["name"]);
```